# Why is my gradient descent for regression in R failing?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have adapted the following gradient descent algorithm for regressing the y-variable stored in data[:,4] on the x-variable stored in data[:,1]. However, the gradient descent seems to be diverging. I would appreciate some help in identifying where I am going wrong.

```
#define the sum of squared residuals
ssquares <- function(x) 
  {
    t = 0
    for(i in 1:200)
      {
        t <- t + (data[i,4] - x[1] - x[2]*data[i,1])^2 
      }
    t/200
  }

# define the derivatives
derivative <- function(x) 
  {
    t1 = 0
    for(i in 1:200)
      {
        t1 <- t1 - 2*(data[i,4] - x[1] - x[2]*data[i,1]) 
      }
    t2 = 0
    for(i in 1:200)
      {
      t2 <- t2 - 2*data[i,1]*(data[i,4] - x[1] - x[2]*data[i,1]) 
      }
   c(t1/200,t2/200)
  }

# definition of the gradient descent method in 2D
gradient_descent <- function(func, derv, start, step=0.05, tol=1e-8) {
  pt1 <- start
  grdnt <- derv(pt1)
  pt2 <- c(pt1[1] - step*grdnt[1], pt1[2] - step*grdnt[2])
  while (abs(func(pt1)-func(pt2)) > tol) {
    pt1 <- pt2
    grdnt <- derv(pt1)
    pt2 <- c(pt1[1] - step*grdnt[1], pt1[2] - step*grdnt[2])
    print(func(pt2)) # print progress
  }
  pt2 # return the last point
}

# locate the minimum of the function using the Gradient Descent method
result <- gradient_descent(
  ssquares, # the function to optimize
  derivative, # the gradient of the function
  c(1,1), # start point of theplot_loss(simple_ex)  search 
  0.05, # step size (alpha)
  1e-8) # relative tolerance for one step

# display a summary of the results
print(result) # coordinate of fucntion minimum
print(ssquares(result)) # response of function minimum
```

Comment: can you share your data?

Comment: This is the dataset that I am using http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv

data <- read.csv("Advertising.csv")[,-1]

Comment: divergence of gradient descent generally indicates a learning rate too high, so reduce learning rate (alpha) to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize your objective / gradient functions for faster implementation, as you can see it actually converges on the randomly generated data and the coefficients are pretty close to the ones obtained with lm() in R:

```
ssquares <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(data) # 200
  sum((data[,4] - cbind(1, data[,1]) %*% x)^2) / n
}

# define the derivatives
derivative <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(data) # 200
  c(sum(-2*(data[,4] - cbind(1, data[,1]) %*% x)), sum(-2*(data[,1])*(data[,4] - cbind(1, data[,1]) %*% x))) / n
}

set.seed(1)
#data <- matrix(rnorm(800), nrow=200)

# locate the minimum of the function using the Gradient Descent method
result <- gradient_descent(
  ssquares, # the function to optimize
  derivative, # the gradient of the function
  c(1,1), # start point of theplot_loss(simple_ex)  search 
  0.05, # step size (alpha)
  1e-8) # relative tolerance for one step

# [1] 2.511904
# [1] 2.263448
# [1] 2.061456
# [1] 1.89721
# [1] 1.763634
# [1] 1.654984
# [1] 1.566592
# [1] 1.494668
# ...

# display a summary of the results
print(result) # coefficients obtained with gradient descent
#[1] -0.10248356  0.08068382

lm(data[,4]~data[,1])$coef # coefficients from R lm()
# (Intercept)   data[, 1] 
# -0.10252181  0.08045722 

# use new dataset, this time it takes quite sometime to converge, but the 
# values GD converges to are pretty accurate as you can see from below.
data <- read.csv('Advertising.csv') # with advertising data, removing the first rownames column

# locate the minimum of the function using the Gradient Descent method
result <- gradient_descent(
  ssquares, # the function to optimize
  derivative, # the gradient of the function
  c(1,1), # start point of theplot_loss(simple_ex)  search 
  0.00001, # step size (alpha), decreasing the learning rate
  1e-8) # relative tolerance for one step

# ...
# [1] 10.51364
# [1] 10.51364
# [1] 10.51364

print(result) # coordinate of fucntion minimum
[1] 6.97016852 0.04785365

lm(data[,4]~data[,1])$coef
(Intercept)   data[, 1] 
 7.03259355  0.04753664
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I did it but still it does diverge for the particular dataset that I am using, that I have attached above. I tried to scale down the data and it seems to work for some scale parameters. But is there any general rule that I should be following? And is there a "more" convergent optimization routine?

Comment: The learning rate (alpha or step size) you are using is very high for the training dataset you are learning on, so it never converges. Use learning rate 0.00001, it will take quite a sometime to converge but it will eventually converge. (also you may want to increase your tolerance for convergence a little bit, not as low as 1e-8, to get a little speedup in convergence).

Comment: @esperanto you don't need to scale your data. updated the code with advertising data, it converges with a much smaller value of alpha, let me know if you face any more issue.

Comment: There are many other sophisticated optimization methods (e.g., L-BGFS-G, CG), but they are not easy to implement from scratch.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help!